# Scan in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am just wondering in which scenario DynamoDB Scan is advantageous over Query? If Scan is time consuming and inefficient why did AWS even have it? We can get entire table dump by using Query. Can someone explain the use Scan?

Comment: Scan returns all items. Query returns some items (those that match the query you provide). I'm not aware that you can issue a query for all items in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We can get entire table dump by using Query.

This is not correct.

Every item in DynamoDB needs a primary key, which can either be the *partition-key* or a combination of *partition-key* and *sort-key*. To `Query`, the least you need to do is supply the *partition-key*. To `Scan`, you don't need to supply anything. In other words, `Scan` operation allows you to *scan* the entire table.